# How can a breakpoint's location affect the findability of a bug?

Tags: debugging, language-agnostic

In [this MSO bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63307/blockquote-glitch-in-editor-in-chrome-6-and-7), our very own waffles makes the following observation:

> This bug also happens to be a heisenbug, when debugging it if your first breakpoint is too early, stepping through shows that everything is good.

(Ref: Wikipedia's [entry on Heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug))

How is it even possible for the location of a breakpoint make a difference in whether a bug appears?

<sub>*(Yes, I know the Wikipedia article answers this, but I thought it'd be a good question for SO to have the answer to, and I bet SO can do better anyways.)*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is any kind of asynchronous activity going on then this could affect *heisenbugs*. e.g. threads, I/O, interrupts, etc. Setting breakpoints in different locations would affect the relative timing of the main thread and the asynchronous events which could then potentially result in related bugs either showing up or disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

A common source is timing, in particular with multiple threads.

Lets say you have a GUI app with some event handlers and a bug where a table selection is not handled correctly, perhaps because Swing sometimes start updating the table before your event is handled.

By pausing a thread at a breakpoint, you may change the order in which the table component receives events and thus you might see a different outcome with and without the breakpoint.  It's a very common problem, and one of the things that can make debugging complex GUI apps with lots of events really painful.